# Next lines of code executes before getting API response in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-observable

In my form there are some Checkboxes. Checkboxes are dynamically generated based on the values getting from API response. If the API response is not null and there is some value then I want to make the checkbox required. But the API response returns null value then the checkbox is not required. This I want in my form. So I have written the below code.

```
Roles: RoleInfo[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
    
    this.accountSubscription = this.regService.getRoles().subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
                this.Roles = data;
            }
        });
    
    if (this.Roles.length > 0) {
        this.arrayInput.setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    else {
        this.arrayInput.setValidators(null);
    }
    
    this.arrayInput.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

But the problem is it does not wait for API response and executes the next lines of code. So the Checkboxes are always set to NOT Required. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to put the if statement which is checking the roles length inside the subscribe callback.

Comment: I don't want it. Because there are so many codes which I didn't put here to make it simplified.

Comment: Well you need to re-structure your code to add some kind of wait on the getRoles function before your if statement. You can either put the if statement inside the subscribe callback, or use async await.

Comment: Is there any other way except using async wait. Is there any RXJS operator to do the things done?

Comment: No, why is it an issue to wrap the if statement? Can you add further details/code to your question to explain this?

Comment: It doesn't matter if *"you don't want"* it. You have to, otherwise it won't work. If there are "so many codes"  this is probably a hint, that you should refactor your code and break it up into smaller parts ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the roles after the API call is complete.

```
Roles: RoleInfo[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
    
    this.accountSubscription = this.regService.getRoles().subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
                this.Roles = data;
                this.checkRoles();
            }
        });
    
    
}

checkRoles() {
  if (this.Roles.length > 0) {
        this.arrayInput.setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    else {
        this.arrayInput.setValidators(null);
    }
    
    this.arrayInput.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```